# Questions about chess.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

I have some questions about chess.stackexchange.com, i read the FAQ but there's no answer.

When did you guys created this site? When will it be officially released? I found it this morning  by googling: "chess stack exchange" I didn't find it by googling a question, and it's not mentioned on the footer of stackoverflow, i consider myself very lucky because i found it.

And the other question, would you analyse ongoing games? Or is it against the rules of the site?

Comment: I found it here http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: @Akavall so we both didn't find it by googling a question, and there aren't many chess websites or forums out there, which is a bad thing for this site

Comment: I think question and answer format is really good for chess topics, because it prevents Looooooong arguments about minor points, or even worse this player is better than that debates. If you posted on chessgames.com you know what I am talking about :). I like the site the way it is right know, and I am sure its popularity will increase in the future.

Comment: @Akavall i agree, i haven't posted in chessgames.com but i have posted in chess.com and i still receive replies after 3 months lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This site's public beta started 10 months ago.  For more stats see our [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551?phase=beta).
2. It won't be officially released until it gets enough participation.  I'm not exactly sure how much is required, but that's when.  See the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)
3. This site is in *beta*.  This is why it is not listed in Stack Overflow's footer.

[image]

Comment: Would you analyse ongoing games? Or is it against the rules of the site?

Comment: @Fischer  I'm pretty sure that would be frowned upon, not to mention against the rules of most websites/clubs.